# How call specific function dynamically that we get in url/path in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

My Code in route.php:-

```
Route::get('/register/{id}',array('uses'=>'UserRegistration@id));
```

I want to call function id (that can be any function of controller) in UserRegistration controller.

Url is like this:- http://localhost:8000/register/test,
http://localhost:8000/register/login

here test and login are function in controller.

Comment: i want to pass anything after register in url, whatever path i pass, that function should be called

Comment: My answer didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

`{id}` is the parameter you're passing to  route. So, for your routes go with something like this:

```
Route::get('/register/id/{id}',array('uses'=>'UserRegistration@id));
                       //this route requires an id parameter 
Route::get('/register/test',['uses'=>'UserRegistration@test]);
```

Comment: i want to pass anything after register in url, whatever i pass, that should be called

Answer (score 0):

Doing this you can call your functions but it is not the recomended way of doing it. Having separete routes foreach function allows for a more in depth control.

```
 public function id(Request $request)
 {
    return $this->{$request->id}($request);
 }
 public function test(Request $request)
 {
    return $request->all();
 }
```